# Interacting with OS functions through C++

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

I am trying to make a tool in C++ that interacts with the OS functions, but I've never did anything similar before, so I don't even have a clue on where to search for an answer.

Here's an overview example of what I would like to make :

Let's say I have a number of text files stored in a folder. Every file has some text in it and a password (just string, no encryptions). What I want to do, is enter a key-word (eg "1", or "2", or whatever the key-word is) and then a password will be selected amongst the files. Now, I know how to do all this "simple" stuff, **my problem comes next :**

Once I find the password - let's say the password will be stored in a String psw variable - I want to copy psw string into the "buffer" (or whatever that is) that my OS (let's say Windows) uses for the function "copy" (Ctrl + C). This resulting in : the next time I hit Ctrl+V, psw will be pasted.

Example of use :
A user runs the .exe and a window opens. He then enters a key-word and a password is selected and added to the "buffer" that handles the "copy" function. The programm may terminate at this state, or wait for another password (we don't care about it anymore). Now, let's say the user creates a text file, hits Ctrl + V and a password is pasted into the text file, without any other interactions from the user-side inbetween.

And here's are my questions :
Is this even possible or should I give up on the idea ?
If yes, I would appreciate any help, tutorial, or some pattern on where to search for this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: With the Windows API, you can use `SetClipboardData` to implement an OS-wide "copy" function. Be very sure to read everything it has to say before using it, however, such as the fact that you should call `OpenClipboard` first.

Comment: Search for "windows clipboard api" or something similar.

Comment: Wow, this starts from 100 miles away and then gets way too descriptive. Which Windows API you're using (Win32, .NET, etc) is way more relevant than what the text might be.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's always [good old Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard). Also, for what it's worth, it's a lot more foolproof with [.NET's Clipboard class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx).

Comment: Google "win32api Charles Petzold". If you really want to go into, I think it's one of the best ways.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers ! It seems there are pretty much nice stuff around this sector that I don't know, I'll surely look into them ! @Potatoswatter hehe, added all the details that might sounded useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a "Windows" answer than it is a "C++" answer, but the code below will work in C or C++.

On windows, you pragmatically "paste"strings into the [clipboard via the Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
void PasteString(const char* pszPhrase)
{
    int len = strlen(pszPhrase);
    BOOL fResult = FALSE;

    fResult = OpenClipboard(GetDesktopWindow());

    if (fResult == FALSE)
    {
        return;
    }

    HGLOBAL hglob = GlobalAlloc(GHND, len+1);
    void* pGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hglob);

    strcpy((char*)pGlobalMemory, pszPhrase);

    GlobalUnlock(hglob);

    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hglob);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```